# String Manipulation using scripts missing 0 in truncation and substitution

Tags: shell-script, scripting, string

I have the following shell commands and want to ensure the `TEST_02` is printed as an output

```
myVer=TEST_03
n=${myVer##*[!0-9]}; p=${myVer%%$n}
lastver=$p$((n-1))
echo $lastver
```

This gives an output `TEST_2` and we miss to follow the track of our test versions as it should have been `TEST_02`, if someone can suggest the right script to do what I intend.

I did try changing

```
n=${myVer##*[!0-9]}
```

to

```
n=${myVer##*[!1-9]},
```

in that case the things will not work well if the value is `TEST_10/TEST_20/TEST_30`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the leading `0` is discarded when the arithmetic context `$((..))` is evaluated where it performs conversion of the numbers to base 10. One way you can preserve the leading `0` by using `printf()` to add the leading zeroes

```
num=${myVer##*[!0-9]}
p=${myVer%%$num}
numLen=${#num}
```

now using this length, do a `printf()` call to add the leading zeros

```
printf -v leadzero "%0*d" "$numLen" "$((10#$num-1))"
lastver="$p$leadzero"
printf '%s\n' "$lastver"
```

You could prefix `10#$` in front of `num-1` to take care of numbers in octal format.